# Syntax Highlighter Evolved Not Working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am completely new to the whole blogging thing and am not the most avid web programmer. I'm more of a desktop guy.

I can not seem to get this Syntax Highlighter thing to work. I installed the plugin to my site and activated it but nothing works. I am trying a test post by writing

```
[c#]string s = "";[/c#]
```

but all I get is that same exact line as a normal string in text. Nothing is formatted.

The syntax plugin seems to have no real tutorial and they hardly keep up with forum posts. Is there anyone on here that is successfully using this and can help me out? Or is there a better way to format code on wordpress?

Comment: @Will I don't see how this comment is "off topic" the FAQ states
**software tools commonly used by programmers** is a valid reason to post a question for and this is not considered a chatty or open ended question. You are saying wordpress is not a _tool_ that is used by programmers. I see lots of programmer's hosting wordpresses along with common how to articles to use on their career 2.0s. By closing this question you are inhibiting me from building my portfolio. This question is and should be valid.

Comment: You're asking how a particular syntax plugin for wordpress works.  That is absolutely off topic.  If you can name the plugin, your question might be acceptable over on [wordpress.se].  And its a bit hyperbolic to say closure is inhibiting your portfolio when you have a selected answer below.  I'd suggest you read our [faq], and [about] pages.  For further clarification, visit [meta].

Comment: You closed the post. No one else can answer so I gave the guy a point for at least trying to help out considering I'm still having the same problem. The plug in is called "Syntax Highlighter Evolved" as it states in the title. But thanks for letting me know there's a question answer system on Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
[csharp]string s = "";[/csharp]
```

instead of

```
[c#]string s = "";[/c#]
```

> I opted to only support aliases with letters, numbers, and dashes to
>   keep things simple and less prone to breaking (WordPress shortcodes
>   probably shouldn't have #'s in them). [Mentioned by author here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-syntaxhighlighter-evolved-c-doesnt-work-as-a-language-alias).